# reply timeout in spring integration tcp gateway

Tags: tcp, spring-integration

Spring integration tcp gateway can be setup as follows:

```
<!-- Server side -->

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="crLfServer"
    type="server"
    port="${availableServerSocket}"
    single-use="true"
    so-timeout="5000"
    using-nio="false" 
    />

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="gatewayCrLf"
    connection-factory="crLfServer"
    request-channel="serverBytes2StringChannel"
    error-channel="errorChannel"
    reply-timeout="10000"/>
```

My TCP server works perfectly fine and responds within 10 seconds.

Sometimes other important batch processes slow down my server processing. During that time, I would like to change reply-timeout dynamically.

How to change the reply-timeout dynamically in a running server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `so-timeout` can be changed on the `AbstractConnectionFactory` bean via that `crLfServer` `id`.

The `reply-timeout` you can change on the `TcpInboundGateway` bean using its `gatewayCrLf` `id`.

Anyway you have to be sure that you restore everything back after those changes.
Plus you application should ensure that nothing more get access to those components. Otherwise you'll end up with unexpected behavior.

On the other hand consider to provide other similar component but just for this particular task with desired timeouts.

Comment: Thats interesting. I looked for gatewayCrLf Mbean which can be used to set reply-timeout. Unfortunately, gatewyaCrLf did not have attribute for reply-timeout. I use
<int-jmx:mbean-export id="integrationMBeanExporter" default-domain="spring.application" />
is it filtering attributes?

Comment: MBean? No, you are mixing concerns. We are here in Spring, so you have to `getBean()` from app ctx, or just `@Autowired` them. We don't talk about JMX here at all.